# Nature of Equilibrium Points

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I would like to prove the following:

"The nature of the equilibrium points (i.e. stability/instability) of a one-dimensional differential equation remains invariant under the effect of the linearization transformation."

Thank you all :)

Comment: can you please add the definition of dynamical system Is it the solution of differential equation $x'=Ax$

Comment: You were right, I meant an one-dimensional differential eq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the [Hartman-Grobman theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem) and depends on the equilibrium being [hyperbolic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_equilibrium_point). (Actually, in a single dimension the behavior is probably nicer but I haven't thought about 1-d in quite a while.)

Unfortunately, [the proof of Hartman-Grobman](https://www.math.hmc.edu/~levy/181_web/Zimmerman_web.pdf) in its usual generality could be considered quite technical by some, but in general it's hard to define what it means for "the nature of an equilibrium point to remain invariant" without referring to topological conjugacy, because in dimensions sufficiently greater than 1 the nature of an equilibrium point can be quite complicated.

Comment: Ok, that was enlightening :) I knew the Theorem but I did not know its applications. Nevertheless, at wiki, I can see an example only around zero. What happens around the rest critical points? Or maybe due to linearity we can "transfer" all the critical points to zero and then we can study them (just a thought, I do not really know how to prove that). Thanks again!!

Comment: You said it exactly right. The derivative is translation-invariant, so you can always move the equilibrium point you want to study to the origin with a change of variables.

Comment: You really help me out here :) Is there any chance that there exists a proof of this statement so that I can see the mathematical way?

Comment: @Mitscaype If you find Nick's answer at all helpful, then you should upvote it. If it "really helps you out", then you might consider accepting it, particularly if another answer doesn't improve on it.

Comment: Well Nick's answer was useful and I now know where to look for more information. Excuse me for not upvoting it, I forgot that. Also, if no further answers appear soon, then I am to accept this answer. Thank you for your your comments.